# Nested Token search batch file

Tags: parsing, batch-file

I have a batch file I am working on trying to use to achieve up IIS server logs. Here is the details of all files involved and the final output I am seeing

Batch file:

```
setlocal
set zipfolder=D:\Statscheck\zipped\
set statsdir=D:\Statscheck\
set statsfolder=Statscheck
d:
cd\
cd\%statsfolder%
dir w3* /s /b > d:\server-scripts\temp\process.txt
set THECSVFILE=d:\server-scripts\temp\process.txt

::read %THECSVFILE% and loop through each line
for /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=\" %%A in (%THECSVFILE%) do (
    set dirname=%%A
)
for /F "usebackq tokens=3 delims=\" %%A in (%THECSVFILE%) do (
    set filename=%%A
    call :process_line
)
:process_line
set buildfile= %zipfolder%stats-%filename%-archive.zip
echo filename %buildfile% >>D:\server-scripts\temp\output.txt
echo directory %dirname% >>D:\server-scripts\temp\output.txt
```

---

`Process.txt`:

```
D:\Statscheck\dphs92\W3SVC1532191319
D:\Statscheck\kcnw\W3SVC232480661
D:\Statscheck\master\W3SVC84257322
D:\Statscheck\warlords\W3SVC1913965975
```

`output.txt`:

```
filename  D:\Statscheck\zipped\stats-dphs92-archive.zip 
directory D:\Statscheck\warlords\W3SVC1913965975 
filename  D:\Statscheck\zipped\stats-kcnw-archive.zip 
directory D:\Statscheck\warlords\W3SVC1913965975 
filename  D:\Statscheck\zipped\stats-master-archive.zip 
directory D:\Statscheck\warlords\W3SVC1913965975 
filename  D:\Statscheck\zipped\stats-warlords-archive.zip 
directory D:\Statscheck\warlords\W3SVC1913965975
```

As you can see from the output it is building the filename option correctly however the directory that is being pulled is the last one in the list. Is it not looping.

Comment: You should run your script with ' echo on'

Comment: I was able to find a way around this happening.

Comment: Normally I do run echo on until I get the script working and then I set echo off.  I was able to find a method that worked. I now have the nested loop looking at two different text files. One pulls the directory path and the uses that to zip of the files using a temp.zip name then the second uses a list that is created that just shows the root directory and does a rename of the temp.zip to the directory name. Most likely the long way of doing what I wanted to do but it works for now. I will start to refine this as I get a better understanding of the way the parsing works.